# How to check runtime log for a batch job submitted using `at` command?

Tags: ubuntu, at

I submit the batch job in Ubuntu 20.

```
at now -f myscript.sh
```

I get an email with a log when the job is completed. But for a time-spending job, I would like to see progress during the execution. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

This will be very verbose however if you add -x to the shell on the first line of myscript.sh, it will show you the line by line execution of your script. The output would be e-mailed to the user submitting the job and also present in the cron log.

Example,
#!/bin/sh -x instead of #!/bin/sh

While the job is in progress, simply tail -f the cron log and you can watch progress. Reminder, this will produce a lot of log data! You may opt to modify your script to show progress along the way somehow?
echo "finished teardown, beginning setup of xxx"

Answer (score 0):

The `at` tool captures stdout of the process and then sends it as log.
So without significant change to the `at` it is not possible to read that log as it is written.

But you can do a workaround with a second log. Just print the 'progress' log into the file with a known name. After that, you can `tail -f` it if you like or ignore it.

In other words, the script you run with `at` would be something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo Started at `date` 
echo Started at `date` > /var/myscript.log
some_long_running_process_with_log >> /var/myscript.log
rc=$?
echo Completed at `date` with return code $rc
echo Completed at `date` with return code $rc >> /var/myscript.log
```

In this case, you would have a short log (with just two lines) for `at` to mail you, and all the log from the long running inner part.

As extension of this approach you can use the `tee`. It allows to duplicate the stdout into the file. Which in turn can help with duplication of log message printing in the script.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo Started at `date` | tee /var/myscript.log
some_long_running_process_with_log >> /var/myscript.log
rc=$?
echo Completed at `date` with return code $rc | tee -a /var/myscript.log
```